# I have used the 'box-sizing' property and set it to 'border-box' in CSS, but still the boxes on my page all look different sizes. What can I do?

Tags: css, image, grid, margin

So I am trying to get all boxes the same size. They are all embedded with one image each though (as well as some text). Maybe it's the image and its size/ shape that's causing this to happen? I'm not sure.

```
.box {
  box-shadow: 0 0.75px 0.75px 0 #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 800px;
}

img {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.description {
  font-family: "Red Hat Mono";
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  margin: 5px 10px 20px 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 350px 350px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 300px);
  gap: 40px;
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
  grid-auto-columns: 400px;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  justify-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: center;
}
```

I thought the 'box-sizing' would help, but it didn't. The only thing that helped me thus far was changing the margins of some of the different elements involved and I don't feel like that's the answer..

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The `box-sizing: border-box;` property in CSS defines the sizing of an element **to include** any *padding* and `border widths` in the **total width and height** of the element. By default, in CSS, the width and height of an element only includes the content area, and padding and border are added to the outside of the defined width and height. You can take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp).

To set all your boxes to a fixed size you need to use the `width` and `height` properties. You can also use [other units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.php) of measure, which work in a **relative** way and not in an **absolute** way.

```css
.box {
  box-shadow: 0 0.75px 0.75px 0 #000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```